# If the status is RECIEVED then background colour is Green

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, search

I want to highlight the row color green if the status in column 7 contains rows with "RECIEVED" value.

The below code is to display the search results data associated with Google sheets to google webapp.

```
var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
var template = templateBox.content;

searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
var l1Column = tr.querySelector(".L1");
var l2Column = tr.querySelector(".L2");
var l3Column = tr.querySelector(".L3");
var l4Column = tr.querySelector(".L4");
var l5Column = tr.querySelector(".L5");
var l6Column = tr.querySelector(".L6");
var l7Column = tr.querySelector(".L7");
var l8Column = tr.querySelector(".L8");

l1Column.innerHTML = r[0];
l2Column.innerHTML = r[1];
l3Column.innerHTML = r[2];
l4Column.innerHTML = r[3];
l5Column.innerHTML = r[4];
l6Column.innerHTML = r[5];
l7Column.innerHTML = r[6];
if (l7Column.innerHTML = r[6] === "RECEIVED") row.style.backgroundColor = "green";
l8Column.innerHTML = r[7];


searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);


});

}
```

I added this **if (l7Column.innerHTML = r[6] === "RECEIVED") row.style.backgroundColor = "green";** but the status showing as false in column 7

[screenshot of the search panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWLFB.jpg)

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: try `if (l7Column.innerHTML === "RECEIVED")` or `if ( r[6] === "RECEIVED")`

Comment: @Sergey the false value is gone but it doesn't highlight the row. with this if ( r[6] === "RECEIVED") row.style.backgroundColor = "green"; or with this  if (l7Column.innerHTML === "RECEIVED") row.style.backgroundColor = "green";

Answer (score 1):

I think that `row` is not used in your script. And, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (l7Column.innerHTML = r[6] === "RECEIVED") row.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

#### To:

```
if (r[6] === "RECEIVED") tr.querySelector("tr").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

### Added:

About your following new question,

> you are so great in script :) than you. it worked, I have a another query, The status doesn't only contain the word RECIEVED but sometime it may have some other words like RECIEVED TODAY or RECIEVED YESTERDAY, in that case how should the script change?

When `r[6]` is `RECIEVED TODAY` and `RECIEVED YESTERDAY`, you want to set the background color to green color. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (l7Column.innerHTML = r[6] === "RECEIVED") row.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

#### To:

```
if (["RECIEVED TODAY", "RECIEVED YESTERDAY"].includes(r[6])) tr.querySelector("tr").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Or, when `r[6]` includes `RECIEVED`, you want to set the background color, how about the following modification?

#### To:

```
if (r[6].toString().includes("RECIEVED")) tr.querySelector("tr").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your question, you are using `RECEIVED`. But in your replying, you use `RECIEVED`. I think that the spel of `RECEIVED` is different from `RECIEVED`. In this addetional modification, `RECIEVED` is used. Please be careful this.

Comment: you are so great in script :) than you. it worked, I have a another query, The status doesn't only contain the word RECIEVED but sometime it may have some other words like RECIEVED TODAY or RECIEVED YESTERDAY, in that case how should the script change?

Comment: Anything that contains RECIEVED Should be highlighted,

Comment: @James Anderson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I added the modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike THANK YOU SO MUCH. I've been struggling for couples of days to figure it out. you are absolutely a genius. May God Bless you. :)

Comment: @James Anderson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.